# Python XGBoost Regressor Error: Feature_names mismatch

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, supervised-learning

I'm trying to use XGBoost Regressor to predict revenue, given some input features. However, I get a feature_names mismatch error when I run it. The features are all numerical features and there are no missing values.

```
cols_to_use = ['Product Visitors', 'Product Pageviews', 'Rating']
X = df[cols_to_use]
y = df['Revenue']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

xgboostmodel = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000, max_depth=7)
xgboostmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = xgboostmodel.predict(X_test)

xgboostmodel.score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['Product Visitors', 'Product Pageviews', 'Rating']['f0', 'f1', 'f2']
expected Product Pageviews, Product Visitors, Ratings in input data
training data did not have the following fields f34, f5, f11, f7
```

Comment: Did you try to write the names directly, like ``X = df['Product Visitors', 'Product Pageviews', 'Rating']``?`It says that it can not find the feature_names.

Comment: I just tried that but the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

The `score` method of xgboost models (or any sklearn-compatible model) has signature `(X_test, y_test)`; see [the docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.score).

The error arises because xgboost is assuming that the `y_test` you pass in is the 2d data, and it thinks the *indices* of the series are the *column names* its expecting; the former are just numbers, hence `f0`, `f23`, `f5`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Ben that is helpful! Based on your expertise, how would I fix it? Pass in xgboostmodel.score(X_test, y_test) ? Is there a way to get the score of predicted data vs the labeled data?

Comment: @Nekojell `xgboostmodel.score(X_test, y_test)` will work, sure.  You can compute the metrics directly from the predictions, e.g. with the functions in `sklearn.metrics`.